# Dismissing the CoC announcement also closes the "join this community" hero banner

Tags: bug, design, announcements

Screencast to demonstrate the issue, more detailed explanation below.
<sup>Sorry for the bad quality, it seems that imgur compresses the gif a bit ... a bit much.</sup>

[image: Screencast showing the problem described in more detail in this post.]

---

On Stack Exchange communities that I have not joined yet, a [hero banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) will be shown that invites me to join that community. Here is an example (using [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)):

[image: Announcement and hero banner on the Travel Stack Exchange community.]

Dismissing the Code of Conduct announcement right below the navigation should not affect anything else, but it also dismisses the hero banner. Starting from the situation depicted in the first screenshot, dismissing only the announcement results in both it and the banner disappearing:

[image: Dismissed announcement and dismissed hero image on the Travel Stack Exchange community.]

I can reproduce this issue on all Stack Exchange communities I have tried it on so far.
Minimizing and dismissing the hero image does not dismiss the announcement though.

Comment: That announcement is about the new Code of Conduct (aka "CoC"), and got nothing to do at all with the "Join Community" hero/banners. Closing one should not have any effect on the other. (So, there's no bug here, just misunderstanding?)

Comment: I noticed that too, but when I inspected the event listeners, it seemed that this could be by design and not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, are you saying that it is expected that closing the announcement also closes the hero image? Given that they have nothing to do with each other and have separate close buttons, I would expect that dismissing one would *not* dismiss the other.

Comment: I have included a(n attempt at a) screencast to demonstrate the problem. It does look like a bug to me, but if it is intentionally confusing then so be it.

Comment: No, the hero is closed because you closed it once and the site remembers this. If you will open it in private/incognito mode you should see it again. The announcement is closed because you closed it and yet again, this is "remembered".

Comment: It is not, @ShadowWizard, please see the screencast I included. As I state in my question, the hero is closed even when starting from the situation in the first screenshot.

Comment: I have removed the two other screenshots as they are evidently confusing.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the so called "hero image" before, and your usage doesn't really seem to match what I see searching Google for the phrase.

Comment: @curiousdannii it's a term used a lot by designers in SE, though I agree it's not very common.

Comment: @Justastudent huh, I see now. Still not totally clear, but hopefully SE developers will see it and fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I just faced this annoying [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) when loaded a Super User question.

From the page's source:

```
// TODO: we should review the class names and whatnot in use here. Older heroes use id selectors, the newer
// sticky question hero on SO has a .js-dismiss class instead, but it's apparently not used anywhere... 
// It's not great. Ideally we'd have a set of classes in the partials above that would correspond to 
// the behaviours we want here in a more clear way. 

// sticky question-page hero at the bottom of the page on SO
$('.js-dismiss').on('click', function () {
```

The problem is that apparently it *is* used somewhere:

```
<a class="grid-cell fc-white js-dismiss js-gps-track"...>...</a>
```

So, basically, the close button for the Code of Conduct announcement also has the event for closing the Join this Community banner.